# How many lines of exactly n points can be placed in a discrete, square grid of size m x m?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

Per the title, I'm seeking the definition of a function $f(n, m)$ which evaluates to the number of lines made from exactly $n$ points which can be placed on a two-dimensional discrete, square grid of size $m \times m$.

My primary interest is the case where $n = 3$, as this is the answer I'm *really* after. I would've raised this question alone, however since I see that [$n = 2$ has been answered](https://mathoverflow.net/q/2806/92343) already, I figured I might as well just generalize the question in hopes that there's some nice, elegant solution out there.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A018810

Comment: See also very similar question by same OP, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/240113/how-many-distinct-sets-of-n-collinear-points-are-there-in-an-evenly-spaced-two-d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this has been answered here by S. Mustonen: [PointsInGrid.pdf](http://www.survo.fi/papers/PointsInGrid.pdf)

There $f(n,m)$ is denoted by $L_n(m)$ and a formula would be 
$$L_n(m)=\frac{1}{2}[f(m,n+1)-2f(m,n)+f(m,n-1)]$$
for $$f(m,k)=\sum_{\substack{-m<kx<m\\-m<ky<m\\(x,y)=1}}(m-|kx|)(m-|ky|)$$

Comment: Apologies, but I haven't encountered that form of sigma expression. Can you please give a quick example as to how it should be expanded?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean: 
e.g. $L_2(2)=1/2(4-(2\cdot4)+(1+2+1+2+4+2+1+2+1))=6$

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. I managed to work backward from your expansion to figure it out well enough to code it up in Python. I was a bit thrown by the bounds of the indexes being defined below the sigma rather than above it.